# HTML.Action Loop results in wrong model on page (variable scope pollution?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor-2

I have a view (cshtml) that has a tab strip on it. The contents of each tab is of course different. The individual tabs have the correct data/information on them. There is some javascript that is intended to fire when a selection is made from the control on the individual tab. As it stands right now the first tab rendered the javascript fires. All other tabs do not fire. Further on the tab that does fire (first one) it obtains the correct value but then when trying to find the matching item in the model it doesn't find a match. Debugging shows that only the data for the last tab is available in the model. Well that explains why no match but begs the question of where did the data the first page was populated with go?

I have snipped the code for brevity. If, in my ignorance I left something out just say so and I'll post whatever is needed.

So to start here is the parent cshtml:

```
foreach (var extbrd in Model.ExternalBoards)
{
  tabstrip.Add()
  .Text(extbrd.ExtForumName)

  .ImageUrl("~/.../ForumTabIcon.png")
  .Content(@<text>
      <div>
          @Html.Action("ActionName", "Controller", new { id = extbrd.BoardId });
      </div>
      </text>);
}
```

Well as you can see above as we loop we call an action in the controller for each tab. Here is that action:

```
public ActionResult ActionName(int extforumid)
{
   //get url for selected forum (tab) and pull feed
   ExternalForums ExtFrm = _forumService.GetExternalForumById(extforumid);
   reader.Url = ExtFrm.ForumUrl;

   return View(reader.GetFeed());
}
```

That's actually it. As above I can post the reader code but I don't think it is the source of the trouble.

Well this action of course has a view and this is where I think things get wacky:

```
@model ExternalThreadsModel

<script type="text/javascript">
  var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.RssThreads))
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#@Html.FieldIdFor(model => model.ExtForumIds)").click(function () {
        var selectedItem = $(this).val();

        var matchingObj = getObjects(model, 'ThreadValue', selectedItem);

        if(matchingObj > 0)
        {
            var $iframe = $('#ForumFrame');
            if ( $iframe.length ) {
                $iframe.attr('src', matchingObj[0].Link);
            }


            var $prevfram = $('#ForumPreview');
            if ( $prevfram.length ) {
                $prevfram.val(matchingObj[0].Description);   
            }
        }

    });
});

function getObjects(obj, key, val) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            objects = objects.concat(getObjects(obj[i], key, val));
        } else if (i == key && obj[key] == val) {
            objects.push(obj);
        }
    }
    return objects;
}

</script>

<div>
<table>

    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ExtForumIds, Model.SelectThreads, new {style = "...", @size = 30})

        </td>
        <td style="width:25px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            @{ Html.Telerik().TabStrip()
                .Name("ForumView")
                .Items(tabstrip =>
                {
                    tabstrip.Add()
                    .Text("Preview")
                    .Content(@<text>
                        <div>
                            <textarea style="background-color:#979797; text-decoration: none;" id="ForumPreview" name="ForumPreview" rows="26" cols="200" readonly></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </text>);

                    tabstrip.Add()
                    .Text("Interactive")
                    .Content(@<text>
                            <div>
                                <iframe id="ForumFrame" name="ForumFrame" src="" style="width:800px;height:350px;"></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </text>);
                })
            .SelectedIndex(0)
            .Render();
            }

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

So as I mentioned each tab does have the correct data / information on it. The problem comes when a user selects an item from the drop down list.

The click handler only fires on the first tab. It doesn't fire for any other tabs???

Further on the first tab the click handler does fire and it pulls the correct selectedItem but when it runs through the helper function getobjects it doesn't find a match.

When I break and examine "model" as it is being passed into getObjects it only contains data for the last tab...so yeah nothing is going to be matched.

What is even stranger for me to understand is the line:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.RssThreads))
</script>
```

In HTML it does render a json object with ALL the data from ALL the tabs...so...somewhere I must be running into variable scope pollution????

Your support and assistance is..as always..greatly appreciated.